# There is no wattage on my screen electrical label

Tags: power, current

I am trying to figure out my screen's wattage. However, there is no wattage on the label. There are only rating values like 100-240V~, 50/60Hz, and 1.6A. How can I calculate my computer screen's wattage?
In the screen's user manual, it is written as 25W but how can this happen? I don't know the power factor and also I am not sure if the screen has an ACDC converter inside.
The screen's model is SE2417HG.

I live in Europe.

Comment: The easiest way is just measure it. A kill-a-watt is like $30 and is a useful thing to have around anyway.

Comment: Dell's own documentation says 17W typical, 25W maximum. Why do you doubt their numbers?

Comment: I am just trying to understand how I can calculate the wattage over those numbers that they have written on the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specs say it is 24W while on. It is 0.10A at 230V.

When sleep it takes something around 1 up to 3W.

You mismatched something anyway. 1.6A is the power supply current at 14V. 14*1.6=22.5W. Round it up and you're about 25W.

You don't need exact wattage - this is enough.

The only way to measure it correctly is to put watt meter or turn everything off at home and watch the energy meter :) You can do the same with more specialized ~AC multimeter if you know how to set it in series.

Comment: A modern switched mode power supply should have a basically constant wattage (technically VA) when the voltage changes within reasonable limits, since if say the voltage rises, it will reduce the pulse width of the switch cycle rather than dissipate extra heat like a simple linear transformer supply would.

Comment: Well that is correct. I've just run too far :) Works only with old transformers. I've removed wrong statement.

Answer (score 0):

The basic calculation is that Power = Volts * Amps. (P=VI).

So 2 Amps at 240 Volts is 480 Watts. In your case, if you are on 230V and the load (power) is 25W, the current is 25/230 = .109 Amps or 109 milliamps. At 120V it would be about double the current for the same power.

The label rating will be the expected maximum, so at any given time the screen is usually drawing less than that, perhaps considerably so. For instance you can generally lower the power consumption significantly by reducing the brightness (which will cause the LEDs doing the backlight to use less power).